# String in data['col'].values but not in data['col']

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I've read a Pandas dataframe from file:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data_here.csv')
```

When I try `"str2try" in df['col2search']` it returns `False`, but when I try `"str2try" in df['col2search'].values`, it returns `True` (and this is what I'd expect in this case).

I don't see why there would be a behavioral difference; I read that `.values` returns the Numpy representation of the column, but why does `"str2try" in <NDFrame representation of column>` return `False`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pandas Series is like a dictionary. `in`  searches its index (or keys) so `"str2try" in df['col2search']`  checks whether the string is in the *index* of that Series:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3]}, index=['x', 'y', 'z'])

df
Out: 
   A
x  1
y  2
z  3

'x' in df['A']
Out: True

2 in df['A']
Out: False

'x' in df['A'].values
Out: False

2 in df['A'].values
Out: True
```

Here's how it would behave in a dictionary:

```
d = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}

'x' in d
Out: True

2 in d
Out: False

2 in d.values()
Out: True
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 0):

Iteration will be valid in case of list or array. Check this below explanation

```
import pandas as pd
frame = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['the cat is blue', 'the sky is green', 'the dog is black']})
In [4]: f["a"]
Out[4]: 
0     the cat is blue
1    the sky is green
2    the dog is black
Name: a, dtype: object
In [5]: f["a"].values
Out[5]: array(['the cat is blue', 'the sky is green', 'the dog is black'], dtype=ob
ject)
In [6]: type(f["a"])
Out[6]: pandas.core.series.Series
In [7]: type(f["a"].values)
Out[7]: numpy.ndarray
```